# Can I static method overload a non static method?

Tags: java, overloading

If I have a method:

```
public void doSomething(String str1, String str2){}
```

can the method below overload the method above:

```
public static void doSomething(String str2, String st1){}
```

Comment: It takes less than 5 minutes to find out yourself by putting sysout message in the methods.

Comment: No, because it doesn’t overload. If you meant override, still no.

Comment: Also worth noting that parameter _names_ are not part of the signature of the method (and depending on arguments given to the compiler and java version, may not even be in the resulting class file).  So the two method signatures aren't different just because the parameter name orders changed.

Answer (score 3):

You ask about overload. But you show an example of override.

You can overload static methods.

You cannot override them, because they do not take part in polymorphism.

**EDIT**

At first I thought your example was about declaring those two methods in different classes. Then it would be an example of overriding.

Now I see that if both methods are on the very same class, then it would mimic a kind of overload. I mean, their signatures (method name and argument types) are the same. But one has the `static` modifier.

I doubt this is valid Java code.

Comment: The question wasn't about overiding a `static` method.  It was about overriding a non-`static` method _with_ a `static` method.  While the answer's still no, there is a difference.  (Assuming in the question that 'override' was intended, not 'overload'.)

Comment: @BeUndead I just realized that. Still thinking about it.